# Product Id of usb device changes automatically

Tags: camera, usb, archlinux, lsusb

I am using 2 usb camera in an archlinux system. Everything was running smooth for a very long time but recently a very strange thing started happening. One of the camera's product id changes suddenly. When I see the output in lsusb.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1409:1225  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1409:1100  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Here, Vendor id is same(1409) but product id has changed.Actual Product id is 1225.
After removing the usb cable and reinserting, it becomes same again.

```
lsusb
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 1409:1225  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1409:1225  
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0020 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I can't understand why the product id would change suddenly and will be automatically correct after reinserting.

Answer (score 0):

Virus infecting all usbs. Everytime you use your usb on a different devices then the id changes to stop you from using that usb to boot a different device.